# C# method returning formula

Tags: c#, methods, return, formula

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double creditcardbalance;
            creditcardbalance = GetPositiveDouble("Enter In Credit Card Balance");

            double monthlypayementamount;
            monthlypayementamount = GetPositiveDouble("Enter In Monthly Payement Amount");

            double percentagerate;
            percentagerate = (int)GetPositiveDecimal("Enter In Percentage Rate");

            CreditCardMonths();
        }

        static void CreditCardMonths()
        {
            double dailyinterestrate;
            double payoff;
            double percentagerate = 0;
            double creditcardbalance = 0;
            double monthlypayementamount = 0;

            dailyinterestrate = (double)percentagerate / 365;
            payoff = (int)(-(1d / 30) * Math.Log(1 + creditcardbalance / monthlypayementamount * (1 - Math.Pow(1 + dailyinterestrate, 30))) / Math.Log(1 + dailyinterestrate)) + 1;

            Console.WriteLine("It will take {0} months to pay off the loan", payoff);
            displaymenu();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Once declaring the method CreditCardMonths() in the main method my answer for my formula returns a negative integer when its supposed to return a positive.??
what am i missing?

my full code is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DebtCalculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double creditcardbalance;
            creditcardbalance = GetPositiveDouble("Enter In Credit Card Balance");
            double monthlypayementamount;
            monthlypayementamount = GetPositiveDouble("Enter In Monthly Payement Amount");

            double percentagerate;
            percentagerate = (int)GetPositiveDecimal("Enter In Percentage Rate");

            CreditCardMonths();
        }
```

This is piece of code works :

```
double creditcardbalance;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in credit card balance:");
            creditcardbalance = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            double monthlypayementamount;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in the monthly payement amount:");
            monthlypayementamount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            double percentagerate;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in annual percentage rate:");
            percentagerate = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            // outputs
            double payoff;
            double dailyinterestrate;

            // Daily interest formula calculated by apr divided by 365
            dailyinterestrate = percentagerate / 365;
            //Introducing formula for output
            //Payoff needed to display whole numbers, although in ints output 1/30 = 0 so adding 1d (double) allows precise calculation.+1 allows it to round up to the nearest dollar.
            payoff = (int)(-(1d / 30) * Math.Log(1 + creditcardbalance / monthlypayementamount * (1 - Math.Pow(1 + dailyinterestrate, 30))) / Math.Log(1 + dailyinterestrate)) + 1;
            //Introduce output for display

            {
                Console.WriteLine("It will take {0} months to pay off the loan", payoff);
                Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
                // keep console open
                Console.ReadKey();
```

But it seems by created a method named CreditCardMonths is returns a negative integer?
Also my method for Y/N for looping is not working.

```
        static void CreditCardMonths()
        {
            double dailyinterestrate;
            double payoff;
            double percentagerate = 0;
            double creditcardbalance = 0;
            double monthlypayementamount = 0;

            dailyinterestrate = (double)percentagerate / 365;
            payoff = (int)(-(1d / 30) * Math.Log(1 + creditcardbalance / monthlypayementamount * (1 - Math.Pow(1 + dailyinterestrate, 30))) / Math.Log(1 + dailyinterestrate)) + 1;

            Console.WriteLine("It will take {0} months to pay off the loan", payoff);
            displaymenu();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }      

        static decimal GetPositiveDecimal(string message)
        {
            decimal value = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            value = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (value <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("invalid input. Please enter a non negative Decimal");
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                value = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            return value;
        }
        static double GetPositiveDouble(string message)
        {
            double value = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            value = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (value <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input . Enter In A Non Negative Number");
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                value = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            return value;
        }
        static void menuItem()
        {
            char menuItem;
            {
                menuItem = GetUpperCaseYN();
                ProcessMenuItem(menuItem);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you, goodbye.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static char GetUpperCaseYN()
        {
            char menuItem;
            menuItem = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            menuItem = char.ToUpper(menuItem);
            while (menuItem != 'Y' && menuItem != 'N')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Menu Item");
                menuItem = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                menuItem = char.ToUpper(menuItem);
            }

            return menuItem;
        }
        static void displaymenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calculate Another? (Y/N)");
        }

        static void ProcessMenuItem(char menuItem)
        {
            switch (menuItem)
            {

                case 'Y':
                   ;
                    break;

                case 'N':
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your CreditCardMonths method and step through it verifying your values. You should be able to find your issue. Also make sure you are not declaring a locally scoped variables that masks a method/class scoped ones

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fact that variables in one method are different variables then variables in the other methods even if they have the same names.

So for instance you have variable  percentagerate in method Main, and variable   double percentagerate in method CreditCardMonths. They are different pieces of memory - different variables. 
You need to  do one of these:
Declare the variables outside of the method - on the class level.
Your methods are statis so you need to include keyword `static`.

```
static double creditcardbalance;
static double monthlypayementamount;
static double percentagerate;

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        creditcardbalance = GetPositiveDouble("Enter In Credit Card Balance");

        monthlypayementamount = GetPositiveDouble("Enter In Monthly Payement Amount");

        percentagerate = (int)GetPositiveDecimal("Enter In Percentage Rate");

        CreditCardMonths();
    }
```

and don't declare them in the second method either becuase it will (so called) hide the scope.

Note: when you learn more about programming, consider passing the data that your sub-methods need to them using method parameters.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx

Comment: elaborate on this please